# Why is Jshint saying "variable already defined" in this if statement?

Tags: javascript, jshint

I have this code:

```
 if ( something is true ) {
        var someVar = true;
    } else {
       var someVar = false;
    }
```

JsHint is saying that "someVar was already defined" on the else statement part. Why is this and how do I fix it?

Thanks

Comment: @thefourtheye with ES6, block scoping now exists in JavaScript using `{}` and `let`

Answer (score 80, accepted):

JS variables do not have block scope, they have "function" scope (or sometimes global).

The declaration (but not the assignment) is "hoisted" to the top of the function.

jshint is warning you that you have two such declarations - your code is equivalent to:

```
var someVar;
var someVar;  // warning!
if (something) {
     someVar = true;
} else {
     someVar = false;
}
```

Answer (score 21):

This is due to hoisting.

In javascript, no matter where you define a new variable with `var`, it moves it to the top of the function you are in.  Your code is producing the following above your if block at the top of the function:

```
var someVar;
var someVar;
```

Here is a tutorial to explain hoisting:

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/quick-tip-javascript-hoisting-explained/

Answer (score 13):

You shouldn't put `var` declarations in such places.  Put the `var` declaration before the `if`, and then just set "someVar" to a value.

Indeed, here you don't need an `if` statement at all:

```
var someVar = !!(something);
```

will do the same thing. (The double application of `!` ensures that "someVar" is set to either `true` or `false`, based on the "truthiness" of `something`.)

Comment: `var someVar = Boolean(something);` does the same thing and is perhaps more readable.